# Avoid insertion of space below section title with aboveskip, belowskip in listings environment

Tags: spacing, listings

I was using the `listings` package to place source code in my document and I noticed that the space between the text and the `lstlisting` environment was to little. So I changed the `\aboveskip` and `\belowskip` properties.

The problem with that was that along with the space I mentioned it was also affected the space between a section header and a `lstlisting` environment which is useless and annoying. Also it does not produce a nice document appearance.

Also I don't know if there is the same behaviour in the space between the environment and page breaks or the beginnings of a new page (is it?) or LaTeX erase that space by itself (if it is actually inserted there too).

My question is how can I prevent the space inserted with `\aboveskip` and `\belowskip` affect the space between section headers, page breaks and beginning of pages?

This is without the `\aboveskip`:

[image]

This is with `\aboveskip=1.5cm` (an excessive number to show the "unnecessary" space under the section title):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\lstset
{
    aboveskip=1.5cm,
    frame=tb,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{BrickRed},
    columns=flexible,
    morecomment=[s][\color{NavyBlue}]{/*}{*/}
}

\section*{Section Title}

\begin{lstlisting}

Source code here.

\end{lstlisting}

Text here!

\begin{lstlisting}

More source code here.

\end{lstlisting}

More text here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show an example? Yes, a MWE is necessary to understand the point.

Comment: Really you don't need to ask: every question is better with an MWE if only to help people test possible answers.

Comment: @David Carlisle I edited my question.

Comment: @egreg I uploaded 2 pictures showing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement seems a little strange but anyway you can make the vale expand to any dimension based on whatever you want to test, here I use `\if@nobreaktrue` as an approximation for "follow heading" it's an internal switch latex uses to avoid page breaks after a heading.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\lstset
{
    aboveskip={\if@nobreak 0pt\else 1.5cm\fi},
    frame=tb,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{BrickRed},
    columns=flexible,
    morecomment=[s][\color{NavyBlue}]{/*}{*/}
}
\makeatother
\section*{Section Title}

\begin{lstlisting}

Source code here.

\end{lstlisting}

Text here!

\begin{lstlisting}

More source code here.

\end{lstlisting}

More text here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why do you think that this is strange?

Comment: @Adam the original "affect where it shouldn't" title made it sound as if the setting was affecting disconnected space choices elsewhere in the document (not impossible in latex:-) but here you are specifying space above a listing and getting space above a listing which seems pretty much exactly what is expected. Space will go at a page break but why after a section but not after other things that add vertical space eg a list or another listing?

Comment: You are right in a way, but I think that the spaces I mentioned shouldn't be affected. I mean it is not logical to add more space under a section as it already has its own, so there should be a different option in case you wanted to do this. The document, in me opinion, would be more beautiful. :)