# Controlling listings `lstlisting` vertical spacing with paragraph breaks ( `aboveskip`, `belowskip`?)

Tags: listings, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

When we have a blank line between text in the LaTeX source, we have a paragraph break.

The fact of the paragraph breaking itself seems to be respected with a `lstlisting` environment.  Specifically, if there is a blank line between the end of the environment and the text, we get a new paragraph indent.  Else, not.

```tex
\end{lstlisting}
There is no paragraph start indent here; all good!
```

```tex
\end{lstlisting}

There \emph{is} a paragraph start indent here; all good!
```

---

However, now I have set an actual gap with:

```tex
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

This is *not* respected by the `lstlisting` environment, although it tentatively seems to be respected by other environments.  Specifically, although a new paragraph can be started with a blank line, there is no additional space below the listing.  A similar problem is present at the top of the environment, with no additional space regardless of whether there is a blank line or not.

```tex
Vertical space \emph{after} this paragraph is the same,
regardless of whether there is a blank line :(

\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}

Vertical space \emph{before} this paragraph is the same,
regardless of whether there is a blank line :(
```

I really want the spacing to be configurable in this way.  Sometimes a listing is its own separate thing, and should be set apart from the text, but sometimes it's just a quick line of code that semantically shouldn't break the flow of the paragraph, or even sentence.

**One disambiguates these choices by line spacing, but the `lstlisting` environment appears not to respect this.  How can I get what I want?**

---

It should be noted that there are keys `aboveskip` and `belowskip`, which I think are the promising avenues for making this happen.  They seem expected to take constants, but (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218756)) also able to take macros.  I tried something like:

```tex
aboveskip={\ifvmode 1em \else 0em \fi},
belowskip={\ifvmode 1em \else 0em \fi},
```

. . . but this did not have the desired effect; the zero case never happens.  I don't know enough to try much else.

Answer (score 0):

Behold: my terrible, brittle, cargo-cult, no-good, very-evil redefinition of `lstlisting` to improve vertical spacing.  It kindof mostly respects different values of `\parskip`, at least in my testing (from 0 to 4em).  It also adds a keyval `break=false` / `break=true` to control whether the environment breaks at page boundaries:

```tex
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\let\lstlisting\@undefined
\let\lstlisting@\@undefined
\define@key{lst}{break}{\def\lstbreak{#1}}
\lstnewenvironment{lstlisting}[1][]{
    \csname\@lst @SetFirstNumber\endcsname
    \def\lstbreak{true}
    \lstset{aboveskip={0pt},belowskip={0pt},#1}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\lstbreak}{true}}{
        \ifhmode\\\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}\else\addvspace{\parskip}\addvspace{0.3\baselineskip}\fi
    }{
        \ifhmode\endgraf\vspace{-\parskip}\else\fi
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \noindent
        \minipage{\linewidth}
    }
}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\lstbreak}{true}}{
        \vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}\noindent
    }{
        \vspace{0.4\baselineskip}\endminipage\vphantom{(p}
    }%
    \csname\@lst @SaveFirstNumber\endcsname%
}
\makeatother
```

My hope is that this is so ultra-cursed that someone who knows more than me can tell me how to do it right.  For now, this is going straight to production.